# Comparative... Marginally, Substantially and Exceedingly above average

Tags: comparatives, degree-of-comparison

Is my understanding of the use of "Marginally", "Substantially" and "Exceedingly" correct as per the depiction below?
[image]

Comment: The relative positions of your phrases are fine.  (Your example sounds kind of silly, though -- "xxx above average"!)

Comment: Thank you @aparente001. You're right. I wanted to call them "xxx High" but remember it now that you pointed out the words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you forgot about the average, you could also use those three words with a different, more common meaning. From 0 to 100%, "marginally" would be near the left "margin", say 5 to 10%; "substantially" would certainly be over 50%, say 60%; "exceedingly" would be around 90%.
In your drawing I think that "substantially" is too close to "marginally", while it should be closer to exceedingly".

Comment: Hehe :) Nice analysis. Yes, you're right. That's a good way to look at the comparatives.